# Restore a system image

Tags: windows-7, restore, disk-image

I created a system image in a network location on Windows 7.

How can I restore this system image in case of a failure?

Answer (score 1):

You need to

1. Open the Control Panel
2. Search for "Recovery"
3. Click on "Advanced recovery methods"
4. Click on "Use a system image you created earlier to recover your computer"

From there just follow the on screen instructions.

[Source](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Restore-your-computer-from-a-system-image-backup)